# Uicollectionview weird gap

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have collection view with custom flow layout and i wonder why i have extra space like that (right side):

[image]

It may hard to notice here, though, but you may see gray gap between right side and cell.

Here is how i override standard collection view flow layout to remove horizontals gaps:

```
@implementation CalendarFlowLayout

- (NSArray *) layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSArray *answer = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];
    NSLog(@"layout blck passed");
    for(int i = 1; i < [answer count]; ++i) {
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *currentLayoutAttributes = answer[i];
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *prevLayoutAttributes = answer[i - 1];
        NSInteger maximumSpacing = 0;
        NSInteger origin = CGRectGetMaxX(prevLayoutAttributes.frame);

        if(origin + maximumSpacing + currentLayoutAttributes.frame.size.width < self.collectionViewContentSize.width) {
            CGRect frame = currentLayoutAttributes.frame;
            frame.origin.x = origin + maximumSpacing;
            currentLayoutAttributes.frame = frame;
        }
    }
    return answer;
}

@end
```

Cell size calculated as follow:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    return CGSizeMake(SCREEN_WIDTH/7, (SCREEN_HEIGHT-NAVBAR_HEIGHT-STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT)/6);
}
```

Those macros above look like that:

```
#define SCREEN_WIDTH  [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width
```

It has been tested and it return correct output.

Also, if i set width to SCREEN_WIDTH/3, there is will be no gap.

How to remove it? Why is that happen?

Comment: Is your screen width a multiple of 7?

Comment: @Kreiri its 375 on iPhone 6 sim.

Answer (score 2):

375 / 3
= 125

375 / 7
= 53.57142857142857

You can't really light a half a pixel, so it is probably rounding down, leaving you with a gap.  Make sure your size is a multiple of your subview size (or add a pixel to the rightmost object if it's not).

Comment: How exactly should i did right rounding to fill all space?

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban you should choose a number x that `375%x==0`, that is 3, 5, 25 or 125

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the width of the cell (eg. `SCREEN_WIDTH/3`) is not a divisor of `SCREEN_WIDTH`. Correct divisors of `SCREEN_WIDTH` (375, as you said in comments) are 3, 5, 25 and 125 (125*3=375).

But As there are different screen size among all iOS devices, I think you should manage the problem differently. For example, you should choose a specific cell width and try to center the collection view in its container, so the extra-space will always be divided on both left and right side of the collection view.